# How to globally enable all of Gentoo's bash completions at once?

Tags: bash, software-installation, gentoo, autocomplete

`eselect bashcomp enable` unfortunately seems to lack a `--all` option, and I certainly don't want to manually activate each of the 194 entries. Can this be automated somehow, and set up such that packages installed afterwards *automatically* have their bash completion activated?

Comment: (Preferably less cumbersome than `for ((i=$(eselect bashcomp list --global | tail -n +2 | wc -l); i>=1; --i)); do eselect bashcomp enable --global $i; done`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer is, No.

Looking at `/usr/portage/eclass/bash-completion{,-r1}.eclass`, the two files that can be used to handle bash completion, neither expose a way to trigger automatic enabling.

So while an individual package could potentially support what you want, that wouldn't solve the problem globally.

Your best bet is probably to open a bug at http://bugs.gentoo.org and request the functionality.

While I don't know in detail what this would work like, I should mention that there could be good reason to not globally enable all of them, hundreds of extra entries could potentially cause significant slow down of bash.